# Why @Inject is not working when implement BeanFactoryPostProcessor

Tags: spring

I have some web app with simple task:

```
public class CustomTask {

    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());

    @Inject
    private CustomDao customDao;



    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, timeout = 600)
    public int run() {      
        customDao.doSomething();
    }
}
```

now it work with no problem. But now I want to add implementation of BeanFactoryPostProcessor (`implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor`)to this task and override this method:

```
@Override
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {

    logger.info(beanFactory.getClass() + "xxxxxxxxxx");

    logger.info("The factory contains the followig beans:");
    String[] beanNames = beanFactory.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    for (int i = 0; i < beanNames.length; ++i)
        logger.info(beanNames[i]);
}
```

but now then I want to do something with `customDao` it throw `NullPointException` and I dont know why because in logger I see that this bean is registred. Can you explain me why this exception occurs and how should I fix it ?

Answer (score 4):

This will not work because `@Inject` (just like `@Autowired`) is detected by `AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor` which is a `BeanPostProcessor`. `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s are instantiated BEFORE any other bean in the application context. So, when your post processor is created, the infrastructure that detects `@Inject` annotation isn't even created and cannot act on your bean factory post processor.

See the [api docs for Autowired annotation](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.2.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/Autowired.html) where there is a note about the restriction for BeanFactoryPostProcessors.

You could make your task to implement BeanFactoryAware and inject the bean yourself:

```
public void setBeanFactory(BeanFactory beanFactory) throws BeansException {
        this.customDao = beanFactory.getBean(CustomDao.class);
    }
```

Comment: You could, also, use java config `@Configuration` and `@Bean` to create your own instance of the task, but be aware of [this restriction](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) specified in the @Bean java doc, related to `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`s.